# Where did the Saml2AuthenticationModule class go?

Tags: authentication, identity, wif, saml

The Microsoft identity team released a CTP package for WIF back in 2011 adding support for the SAML 2.0 authentication protocol.

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2011/05/16/ATTENTION-ASP-NET-DEVELOPERS-SAML-P-COMES-TO-WIF/

Unfortunately the [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/site1168/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=36088) to the Microsoft Connect site is dead. Since most WIF functionality has been moved into .NET 4.5 System.IdentityModel namespace, I was hoping to find the `Saml2AuthenticationModule` class there. However, I cannot find that class anywhere in the identity model assemblies.

Does anyone knows what happened to the SAML 2.0 support classes? Where they migrated to .NET 4.5 System.IdentityModel namespace? If not, is the original CTP package available somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WIF SAML stack never made it out of CTP. Had a look around and can't find it anywhere.

It was based on WIF 3.5 so wouldn't run under WIF 4.5 anyway.

My guess it that it was removed because SAML support is non-trivial and you can get the same functionality by federating via ADFS or Azure Active Directory.

There are other libraries available - refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I figured as much. It's strange that Vittorio announces this as the most requested feature in WIF and then it dies a silent death.